# What is the probability of touching point A first?

Tags: options, equities, probability, statistical-finance, barrier

The probability of a stock touching a point A which is below the current spot price is 35%, and the probability of the stock touching a point B which is above the current spot price is 20%.

How can I calculate the probability of the stock touching point A(**but B must not have been touched before A is touched**)?

Comment: This is a bit difficult to answer as you haven't specified a model for your stock!

Comment: If you don’t mind, please what do you mean by model? Is it the distribution?

Comment: Yes, I mean the "distribution". Is your stock assumed to be log normal (e.g. Black-Scholes)? Or normal (Bachelier)? Or other distributions?

Comment: Ok assuming a normal distribution, can there be a solution?

Comment: @immediate_blood: normal sort of makes sense but,  more precisely, do you mean that the log price follows a geometric brownian motion ?

Comment: Isn't the probability of hitting A before B just 20/(20+35) = 0.364 ? (Assuming a symmetric random walk).

Comment: noob2: I think you're right for symmetric random walk but I don't think geometric brownian motion is the continuous analog of a symmetric random walk because of the skew of the lognormal. So, the model specification definitely matters. But, for symmetric RW, I think you're right. hopefully, an sde person can chime in here to set me straight.

Comment: @noob2: I've been thinking about this and I'm pretty certain that the process has to be a symmetric random walk. The reason I think this is because any other model would require you to know where you started and, since that information isn't given, I would think the process being a symmetric random walk makes the most sense. Note that since, 35 is greater than 20, the starting point must be closer to point A than B. But that's all one needs to know. The specific starting point doesn't matter like it would in the case of other processes.

Comment: Thanks guys for that answer. Noted: symmetric random walk model.

Comment: If the probabilities is changed to 15% at A and 15% at B, that means I would get 15/(15+15) =50% as the probability? I don’t know how you arrived at that formula? @noob2

Comment: I don’t know if you can help also with my follow up question? @mark leeds

Comment: I am using points rather than percentages, but yes: if the particle starts at 0, the upper barrier is 15 and the lower barrier -15, then the chance that A is touched first is 50%. This assumes no drift up or down and equally likely movements +1 or -1 by the particle at each step. (So it is slightly different from your problem, as Mark Leeds pointed out it is not GBM).

Comment: I thought about this some more and I don't think the question of what the model is, is even relevant. So, I like the assumption of symmetric random walk since it's kind of the same as a "no model" assumption but I think noob2's answer is correct, independent of the model assumed.  AFAIK, the answer is always  prob of reaching A divided by ( prob of reaching A + prob of reaching B ) and underlying process-model not relevant, given the information provided.

Comment: Alright. I get it now. Thanks.